# Variadic function without nil termination

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, ios, preprocessor

I am trying to create a method like the following:

`- (void)setCondition:(NSString *)format, ... NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2);`

But since I'm not great with preprocessor, I hit an issue that I have fixed in the following code snippet, but I'd like to know if there's not cleaner way to achieve what I want which is to stop after the provided arguments

```
+ (CRCondition *)conditionWithFormat:(NSString *)format,... {
CRCondition *condition      = [[CRCondition alloc] init];

NSArray *conditionSliced    = [condition sliceFormatOperationFromString:format];

condition->_leftOperand     = [[conditionSliced objectAtIndex:0] retain];
condition->_operator        = [condition operatorFromString:[conditionSliced objectAtIndex:1]];
condition->_rightOperand    = [[conditionSliced objectAtIndex:2] retain];

id eachObject;
va_list argumentList;

va_start(argumentList, format);
while ((eachObject = va_arg(argumentList, id))) {
    if ([condition->_leftOperand isEqualToString:@"%K"]) {

        [condition->_leftOperand release];

        if ([eachObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            condition->_leftOperand = [eachObject retain];

        else
            condition->_leftOperand = [[eachObject description] retain];
    }

    else if ([condition->_rightOperand isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] &&
             [condition->_rightOperand isEqualToString:@"%@"]) {

        [condition->_rightOperand release];
        condition->_rightOperand = [eachObject retain];
    }

    else
        break;
}
va_end(argumentList);

if (![condition isOperatorValid]) {
    NSException *exception = [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Invalid Condition Operator" 
                                                     reason:@"The operator passed is invalid. Must follow the following regex pattern: ([(=><)|(A-Z)]{1,2})" 
                                                   userInfo:nil];
    [exception raise];
}

return [condition autorelease];
```

}

The problem is with the while loop that circles and go past the provided arguments (I'm aware of why it's providing me other value, cmd args and such)

If you need any more explanation please add comments so I can get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach would be to parse the format string first and figure out how many arguments should follow it based on that (there is usually exactly one valid number of arguments for any format string). If the number of arguments is not deducible from a format string, it is common to terminate the list with nil (as in `arrayWithObjects:...`).

Comment: The 1st approach you mention is exactly what I'm doing right now (see the code above). nil termination is useful when you create arrays but quite pointless when doing stuff using format string (as in `stringWithFormat:...`

Comment: Could be that I'm missing something, but it seems that you're looping through all arguments that are given, instead of stopping after you've seen all arguments specified by the format string.

Comment: The method `NSArray *conditionSliced    = [condition sliceFormatOperationFromString:format];`is in fact making CRCondition out of the format. I then loop through arguments until I either don't have arguments to pass, or that I hit the `break`instruction if it doesn't fit for the _leftOperand & the _rightOperand