# c function declaration in xcode / to replace NSLog with something that behaves differently in debug and release 

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

It is a rather silly question! but in the following function how do you use the remaining arguments passed in:

```
void NSLog(NSString *format, ...)
{
    //here I can use "format" but how can I use the remaining arguments?
}
```

It is hard to find the answer to this question because I cant search for "..." ?!
By the way that is how NSLog works but I put it here just as an example my question has nothing to do with NSLog.

Comment: Read section 15 of [the c-faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: By the way, this is also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002969/variadic-function-without-nil-termination

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a variable argument list:

```
void NSLog(NSString *format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);

    while( (value = va_arg(args, NSString *) ){
        // Do something with value. This is assuming they are all strings
    }

    // or pass entire list to another function
    NSLog_VA( format, ap );

    va_end(ap);
}

void NSLog_VA( NSString * format, va_list args )
{
    // do something with va_list here
}
```

Edit: 
Since you want a debug only log:

```
#ifdef DEBUG 
#define DebugOnly_Log(format, args...) NSLog(format, ##args) 
#else 
#define DebugOnly_Log(format, args...) // defined to nothing
#endif
```

Comment: Its the [token pasting operator.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y(v=vs.80).aspx)  [It's used to keep a comma from being passed though if there are no additional args](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [stdarg.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h)

It might look a bit like -

```
void NSLog(NSString *format, ...)
{

  va_list args;
  va_start(args,format);
  vprintf([format cString], args);
  va_end(args);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's called a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), and you can access its arguments by using the macros in [stdarg.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h).

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks all, I followed the direction you gave me and this is the solution:
As I understand it, there is no general/portable solution to the problem of receiving variable number of arguments and passing them to another function that accepts variable number of arguments (as mentioned her http://c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html ).

But I wanted to implement an NSLog alternative (I call it AliLog ) which during debugging just behaves like NSLog but for the release version does nothing (or does something other than writing to consol).

here is my solution:

```
void AliLog(NSString *format, ...) 
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    NSLogv(format, args);
    va_end(args);
#else
    // do nothing! or something that makes sense in a release version
#endif
}
```

The magic is in `NSLogv` here.

Comment: You could do the same thing with a macro:
    #ifdef DEBUG
    #define DebugOnly_Log(x, args...) NSLog(format, ##args)
    #else
    #define DebugOnly_Log(x, args...)
    #endif

Comment: Whoa sorry for mess, I don't know how to make code formatting work in comments

Comment: Sorry I can't get it to work, would you please put it in an "answer" with formatting?